# Loading unspecified classes from package to list C#

Tags: c#, import

Hi i recently converted from python to C#, now is it possible to load classes just based on package name to parse classes into a list, all my classes derive from a base class and are all children classes, if the person reading this would know any python, the same equivalent as looping through a directory with the importlib module is what i'm attempting to do.

Package:

- class1
- class2

  List classes = List->classColection(package);

Comment: [Assembly.GetTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes, but first you need to actually load the assemblies from the directory, using something like [Assembly.LoadFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_).  Though note that .NET Core behaves differently than .NET Framework when doing this.  Here's a good read about loading assemblies into different contexts in .NET Core: [Understanding AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext)

Comment: @SeanSkelly Thanks for that, Alexanders comment alone was a bit unclear, Should get me where i need it.

Comment: Also note that when looking for types that implement your base class, you can filter the array of types you get from Assembly.GetTypes by using [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netcore-3.1), such as `baseType.IsAssignableFrom(possibleDerivedType)`, where the possible derived types come from your loaded assemblies.